# Python, WebScraping for Weather values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Long story short, I've googled to no solution, and finally after years of lurking in the shadows I'm registering myself on stackoverflow :)

I'm trying to grab weather values from accuweather or any other site, but I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "weather.py", line 9, in
>   
>       request = urllib2.Request(site, headers=headers) NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined

I'm learning python so please excuse me if this is a basic issue that I'm wasting your time with.

Here's my code:

```
# import libraries
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"}
# specify the url
site = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/aq/mcmurdo-station/2273718/current-weather/2273718"

request = urllib2.Request(site, headers=headers)

page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = page.read()

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
temp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'h2'})
print temp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Dear downvoters please add your comment. From the error message - it is clear that You only imported the name urlopen, REquest ,etc.,, not the urllib2 module. use  import urllib2

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to have a look on the beautiful crawling library Scrapy

Comment: or remove urllib2 from urllib2.Request(site, headers=headers)

Comment: Thank you so much.

However, not there's just no input when I run the script.

Comment: Can you please  give me more details. I do not understand

Answer (score 3):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, HTTPError
```

Here you are importing from the urllib2 library, which means you don't reference urllib2 when calling one of the modules you imported. So instead of:

```
request = urllib2.Request(site, headers=headers)
```

It would just be:

```
request = Request(site, headers=headers)
```

To drill that home more, because I used to be confused by that, too, you already do the exact same thing with from bs4 import BeautifulSoup. Notice how you don't call bs4.BeautifulSoup, but just BeautifulSoup.

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

You do this again here, and you also are passing in 'req' instead of the 'request' object you just made.

And finally, if you've fixed that, you are likely getting no output because of this line:

```
temp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'h2'})
```

You are asking for a 'div' with the class of 'h2'. h2 is an HTML element in itself, and not a class attribute, unless it's a very funky website.

Good luck with your project!